# HTML5 canvas in android problem

Tags: android, html, canvas

I want to make a  gradient text with canvas and my pc renders the code correct, but android displays it like normal gradient with the text inside of it. How can i solve this problem, if it's possible?
Here's the javascript:

```
function text() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('header-text');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 29);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "#fcfcfc");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ccc");
ctx.font = "bold 29px helvetica, arial, sans-serif";
ctx.shadowColor = "#232323";
ctx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
ctx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
ctx.shadowBlur = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillText("Company name", 0, 23);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code in question? There is more than one way to make a gradient on text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, it's a bug.

Or rather, the gradient for fillText is not yet implemented on the android browser. If you write this:

```
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 29);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "#fcfcfc");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ccc");
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillStyle = gradient; // replace the fillstyle with a gradient
ctx.fillText("Testing", 0, 23);
ctx.fillRect(0,0,20,20)
```

You will see that both the text and the rectangle have the gradient in Chrome.

[See it live here](http://jsfiddle.net/SYLW2/50/).

But on the android device the text will be red and the rect will be a gradient!

Chrome itself still doesn't have full support for all the canvas gradient cases that were laid out by the specification author (himself a Google employee). I submitted a bug report about it [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54070).

Comment: just to add the gradient doesn't appear to be working for `arc` as well.